# Autopublish album in Google+ photos

Tags: android, instagram, google-plus-photos

Okay, in spite of the hate being heaped on by iPhone elitists, I have installed Instagram on my Android phone and have started playing with it a bit.

**How can I get my Instagram photos to automagically appear in a public album in Google+ Photos?**

Felicia Day, for instance, has [a public Instagram album](https://plus.google.com/photos/110286587261352351537/albums/5627898447762720193).

I can see, on my phone, an Instagram album (which was automatically created by the app), but there is no such album in my Google+ Photos. The options for the phone album do not include a "make public" option, and there's nothing in the Instagram settings. At best, the photos are appearing in the default "Photos from your phone" album.

I know that I can manually share them, either through the website by making a public album and moving/copying them there, or using the Share features on my Android, but I'd rather have something automatic.

Is this possible, or just a pipe dream?

([Cross-posted at *Android Enthusiasts*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/21476/267).)

Comment: Have you tried [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com)?

Comment: @Cawas: I hadn't, but I see a couple of pre-built recipes that might serve. I'll check 'em out.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: the email upload feature was recently removed from Picasa Web Albums. This solution no longer works.*

I was able to solve this by using [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com) (thanks @Cawas) and the email upload feature of [Picasaweb](http://picasaweb.google.com). Because Picasaweb albums are shared with Google+ this gives me what I want.

Here's what you need:

1. [Turn on the **email upload** feature of Picasaweb](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83342)

   1. Sign in to your account at http://picasaweb.google.com/.
   2. Click the gear gear icon icon in the top-right corner and choose Photos settings.
   3. On the General tab, in the "Upload photos by email" section, select the "Allow me to upload photos by email." checkbox.
   4. Enter a "secret word," 6-15 characters long. As you enter this word, an email address appears.
   5. Click the Save changes button.
   6. To email upload your photos, just attach them to an email message and send it to the newly-created address.
2. Create an album in Picasaweb and make it public. I named mine "Instagram".
3. Set up the [Instagram to Picasa recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/620) on IFTTT.com.

   1. Set the email address to send to to be the same one set up in step 1.4.
   2. Set the email subject to be equal to the name of the album created in step 2.
4. Take Instagram photos!

Technically, you just need a recipe that takes from Instagram and sends an email message, but this recipe explains why it works and gives credit to the source.

If you want to get fancy, there are a few triggers you can use on the Instagram channel to only share photos with a particular tag, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The new Google Photos app for Android let users to choose the folders to back up.

> Check how and when your photos and videos are saved to your Google
>   Account.
>
> 1. Open the Google Photos app on your mobile device [image: Google Photos icon].
> 2. At the top left, touch the menu icon [image: menu icon].
> 3. Select Settings > Back up & sync.
> 4. If "Back up & sync" is on, you'll see these options:

...

> Choose folder to back up

**References**
[Change “Back up & sync” settings - Google Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6156060?hl=en&ref_topic=6156061)